# Can a cleric select an alignment domain that is not offered by his deity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, alignment, domains

SRD:

> A cleric’s deity influences his alignment, what magic he can perform, his values, and how others see him. A cleric chooses two domains from among those belonging to his deity. A cleric can select an alignment domain (Chaos, Evil, Good, or Law) only if his alignment matches that domain.

Does that second sentence mean a cleric with a deity can select an alignment domain that his deity doesn't offer, as long as the cleric matches it? Or does it mean a cleric can only select from his deity's domains, and any alignments his deity offers that don't match the cleric are banned?

For example:
Fharlanghn (true neutral) offers Balance, Celerity, Luck, Portal, Protection, Travel, and Weather domains.

Can a Lawful Neutral cleric of Fharlanghn take the Law domain?

Answer (score 12):

No, it means that *if* their deity offers an alignment domain, they can only select it if their alignment matches the domain.

Answer (score 4):

> Can a cleric select an alignment domain that is not offered by his deity?

**No**.

There are two restrictions, and *both* apply:

1. At 1st level, a Cleric may only select its domains from those of its deity
2. A Cleric may only select alignment domains if they match its own alignment

If you have a mathematical mind, a Cleric may choose alignment domains from the *intersection* of the set of domains offered by its deity *and* its own alignment.

---

Let's see some examples!

> Fharlanghn domains are Balance, Celerity, Luck, Portal, Protection, Travel, and Weather.

A Cleric of Fharlanghn may not select any alignment domain, because Fharlanghn has none (as suited to its True Neutral nature).

> Tyr domains are **Good**, Knowledge, **Law**, Retribution and War.

A **Lawful Good** Cleric of Tyr may select both **Good** and **Law** (but need not to).

A **Lawful** *Neutral* Cleric of Tyr may select **Law**, but not *Good*.

A *Neutral* **Good** Cleric of Tyr may select **Good**, but not *Law*.

An hypothetical<sup>1</sup> *True Neutral* Cleric of Tyr may select neither *Good* nor *Law*.

<sup>1</sup> *Hypothetical because (1) Clerics are supposed to be within one step of their deity's alignment, and True Neutral is two steps from Lawful Good and (2) as noted by Hey I Can Chan, Clerics can only be True Neutral if their deity is True Neutral.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan: Amended.